# What's the Intent to open DND settings?

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm sure I'm overlooking something in the [`Settings`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#constants) class documentation. What `Intent` can open the Settings app in the "Do not disturb" section?

I expected it to be the [`ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS) action, but that is only for the screen which lists which apps have requested DND access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Update

Looking at the [`AndroidManifest.xml` for the *Settings* app](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/android-5.0.0_r1.0.1:packages/apps/Settings/AndroidManifest.xml;l=599) there is an `Activity` `Settings$ZenModeSettingsActivity` already from Android 5.0.

To send the user to the "Do not disturb" screen you can use the action `android.settings.ZEN_MODE_SETTINGS` like this:

```
try {
    startActivity(new Intent("android.settings.ZEN_MODE_SETTINGS"));
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO: Handle activity not found
}
```

#### Original answer

**It looks like there are no screens in the Settings app (at least on Android 6+7) where you can enable/disable DND.** It seems like this is only available through the settings tile (and can be disabled in the dialog when changing the volume).

I have a Samsung S6 (Android 6.0.1) which has this screen, but this is probably some custom Samsung changes. The screen is represented by the class `com.android.settings.Settings$ZenModeDNDSettingsActivity` which can be started by any app. This might be of help for some people out there.

`AndroidManifest.xml` for Settings app for Android 6+7:

- https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/android-6.0.1_r68/AndroidManifest.xml
- https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/android-7.0.0_r6/AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the following `Intent`: [ACTION_VOICE_CONTROL_DO_NOT_DISTURB_MODE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_VOICE_CONTROL_DO_NOT_DISTURB_MODE) and then pass a `boolean` through [EXTRA_DO_NOT_DISTURB_MODE_ENABLED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#EXTRA_DO_NOT_DISTURB_MODE_ENABLED).

Make note that the documentation specifies the following: `This intent MUST be started using startVoiceActivity.`

Comment: I see you got 2 upvotes, but I'm not entirely sure how that action can be used to open the Settings app at the DND section. And I can't find any examples on how VoiceInteractionSession (which has startVoiceActivity()) is supposed be used. The app only crashes when trying to manually instantiate the object and doing the needed life cycle calls for it. Any real code for doing what you suggest would be appreciated.

Comment: It seems like this is more meant for if you have a VoiceInteractionService..?